# Accessing target button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to target the following button using jQuery

```
<button id="mybutton" 
        book_title="{{$book->title}}"
        author="{{$book->author}}"
        idx="{{$book->id}}"
        class="btn btn-success b_r_20 btn-xs pull-right"
        >
    Borrow
</button>
```

After clicking the button, I want to display an `alert()`.

Here is my **HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-12 m-t-35" >
        @foreach($books as $book)
            <div class="bg-white section_border ">
                <div class="row" >
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-12 center">
                        <img src="{{URL::to($book->photo)}}" style="height: 180px;width: auto; padding-left: 5px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9" >
                        <h4 class="m-t-10">
                            {{$book->title}}
                        </h4>
                        <h5 class="m-t-5">
                            Author: {{$book->author}}
                        </h5>
                        <h5 class="m-t-5">
                            Category: {{$book->category}}
                        </h5>
                        @if(Auth::user()->role == "Manager" || Auth::user()->role == "Staff")
                            <h5 class="m-t-5">
                                Shelve: {{$book->shelve->title}}
                            </h5>
                        @endif
                        <div class="m-t-15 p-b-15">
                            <h5 class="pull-left">
                                For Sale: {{$book->copies_forsale}} copies
                            </h5>
                            <h5 class=" pull-right">
                                Borrow: {{$book->copies_forborrow}} copies
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="m-t-15 p-b-15">
                            <button class="btn btn-success b_r_20 btn-xs pull-left">
                                Purchase
                            </button>
                            @if(($book->borrowing_requests->count() == 0) || ($book->purchasing_requests->count() == 0))
                                <button class="btn btn-danger b_r_20 btn-xs pull-right">
                                    Delete
                                </button>
                            @endif
                            <a title="edit this book" href="{{url('book_edit/'.$book->id)}}">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary b_r_20 btn-xs pull-left">
                                    EDIT
                                </button>
                            </a>
                            <button id="mybutton" book_title="{{$book->title}}" author="{{$book->author}}" idx="{{$book->id}}" class="btn btn-success b_r_20 btn-xs pull-right">
                                Borrow
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
        @endforeach  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: IDs _have_ to be unique within an HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

To target that button:

```
$('#mybutton').on('click', function() {

});
```

And then you add the `alert()` to inside the event handler:

```
$('#mybutton').on('click', function() {
    alert("Hello, World!");
});
```

**In pure Javascript:**

```
var btn = document.getElementById('mybutton');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert("Hello, World!");
});
```

Comment: I have tried many possible way but didn't work out including that @martinGeldart

Comment: I think you to start from outside the target button before accessing it that's why I have decided to paste the whole html codes here

Comment: @TheodoryFaustine: then you must have a mistake elsewhere on your page. Please see this demo for proof this will work https://jsfiddle.net/k8qdLgb7/

Comment: I know that will work brother but when you're having many classes before target you have to start from outside something like $("#id").find("#mybutton").click() then you will access it through that but the simple one like that will not workout in my case

Comment: No, you don’t have to “start outside”, you have to start by fixing the basic mistake of using an id multiple times - ids *must* be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: @TheodoryFaustine - that's not how it works, as CBroe explained. You don't have to 'start outside', you can't just simply select the element directly with an ID - that's what IDs are for. As I said, you must have an error elsewhere on your page for this simple task not to work. As Cbroe suggests, you probably have duplicate ID's on your page. Do you have more than one button with ID of 'mybutton'?

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery

```
$(function() { $("#mybutton").on("click", function () { alert("clicked");} });
```

Comment: That didn't work because you have to start from outside of the target button something like this $("#id").find("#mybutton").click()

Answer (score 0):

Complete code for alert button.

```
<html>
<body>


 <div>
       <button id="mybutton" book_title="{{$book->title}}" author="{{$book- 
       >author}}" idx="{{$book->id}}" class="btn btn-success b_r_20 btn-xs 
       pull-right">Borrow</button>
 </div>
 <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#mybutton").click(function(){
         alert("ok.");});
         });
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Can you help me from my html structure bro am aware of that but in my case will not workout

Comment: Using Jquery 
   <script>

                $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#mybutton").click(function(){
                alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
                });
                });
    </script>

Comment: Its work perfectly with your code i edited my ans you can run my code in your IDE.